# Using modelsummary() 'shape' argument as alternative to deprecated modelsummary_wide()

Tags: r, nnet, modelsummary

I'm running a multinomial logit model using nnet, and then want to display the results, with the factor levels as columns, in a modelsummary table:

```
library("nnet")

multi <- multinom(DV ~ var1, data = wave1)

alpha <- summary(multi)$coefficients / summary(multi)$standard.errors
abs(alpha)
# Calculate p values by hand
p_values <- (1 - pnorm(abs(alpha))) * 2
p_values

library("modelsummary")
modelsummary_wide(multi, output = "gt", stars = TRUE)
```

Previously I did this using modelsummary_wide(), but this is now apparently deprecated and I should use the shape argument in modelsummary().

However, I can't really figure out how to do this. Could someone offer me some tips on this?

Thanks

Comment: There's are several examples on the website, including some with exactly this kind of `nnet::multinom` model: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#shape-pivot-groups-panels-and-stacks

Comment: Ah thank you! I hadn't seen that

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @Vincent

Using this arrangement:

```
modelsummary(multi, stars = T, shape = model + term ~ response)
```